# How to add source/dependency to a IntelliJ project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to write some scripts/addons for [freeplane](http://freeplane.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). I cloned the [github repository](https://github.com/freeplane/freeplane) and created a new project in IntelliJ (`File→New→Project`).
I opened `File→Project Structure`, clicked the + Button in `Modules→Depencies` and tried to add the freeplane source to my project (with `+ Button`→`JARs or Directories` and `Libraries...`), according to the [manual's description](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-project-and-global-libraries.html#d1604025e18641).

Neither of them worked. IntelliJ Idea creates every time an empty library:
[image]

But the *.java sources do exist.

```
$ ls -lR /media/[…]/freeplane/ | grep ".java" | wc -l
1400
```

I can't import classes from freeplane. What did I do wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: If it's on Maven repository, you can use Maven to resolve dependencies. It's the preferred way with large Java projects.

Comment: Why not `Import Project` and point to the `build.gradle` file?